# Importing CSV into QGIS with Python, Specific Parameters?

Tags: qgis, python, csv

I would like to know where I can find a list of parameters that can be specified when importing a CSV into QGIS using python.  The documentation I've found only shows a few options.

[QGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)

I would like to specify the number of lines to skip, and the fields of the X and Y when there isn't a header.  How do I find the complete list of options?

Comment: Bumping this to the top as I would still like to know the answer (3 years later)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the parameters required while importing a delimited text file: (String values are usually **case-insensitive**. `Yes`, `yes`, `YES` are all valid)

| key | value(s) |
| --- | --- |
| crs | e.g. `epsg:4326`, `EPSG:3857` |
| type | `csv`/`regexp`/`whitespace` |
| delimiter | <delimiter character(s) or regular expression> |
| xField | <field name> |
| yField | <field name> |
| zField | <field name> |
| mField | <field name> |
| spatialIndex | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| subsetIndex | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| watchFile | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| geomType | `none`/`point`/`line`/`polygon` |
| wktField | <wkt field name> |
| maxFields | number |
| quote | <quote character> e.g. `"` |
| escape | <escape character> e.g. `"` |
| skipLines | number |
| skipEmptyFields | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| useHeader | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| xyDms | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| trimFields | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| encoding | <encode> e.g. `utf-8`, `turkish`, `latin1` |
| subset | ??? |
| detectType | `yes`/`no`/`y`/`n` |
| decimalPoint | <decimal character is comma> -> `,` |
| booleanTrue | <text for True> e.g. `true`, `True`, `TRUE`, `OK` etc. |
| booleanFalse | <text for False> e.g. `false`, `False`, `FALSE` etc. |

Uri structure:

```py
uri = f"file://{file_path}?key=value&key=value&..."
```

References:

- [qgsdelimitedtextfile.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/delimitedtext/qgsdelimitedtextfile.cpp)
- [qgsdelimitedtextsourceselect.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/delimitedtext/qgsdelimitedtextsourceselect.cpp)

Comment: What is your reference?

Comment: Actually I just reviewed the source files.